# Apex Oracle 4.2 - How to edit the page template HTML

Tags: oracle-apex

I can't find the proper way to edit the HTML of the page template I'm using. What I want to do is to edit the "Welcome User" section on top right of the page, and add a dropdown menu to add some functionalities for the user, like a "Change Password" section.

[image: Welcome User section]

If I go to Application Builder -> Application -> Shared Components -> Templates I can see the HTML of the body section, but I'm not able to edit it. When I save some edit I'm always getting this error that says that the page does not work.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What error is that?

Comment: @TonyAndrews I've edited the post with the error I get

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the new version of Chrome browser but all changes you did in the template was saved in database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyway the edited HTML is not printed on screen.